# Running multiple SQL commands in mysql

Tags: mysql, delphi

The code I am trying to write with Delphi 7 is below. But I could not run more than one MySQL command in one operation.
I want to;

```
A- customer table >>> address_id, customer_id, firstname, lastname,
B- address table  >>> address_id, customer_id, firstname, lastname
C- customer table >>> address_id,

B = A and C = B
```

I need to code in the form of.
How do I need code for mysql?

```
modul.Q_Customer.Close;
modul.Q_Customer.SQL.Clear;
modul.Q_Customer.SQL.Add('INSERT INTO customer (customer_group_id,firstname, lastname, email, approved, ip, model, telephone, fax, status, date_added)');
modul.Q_Customer.SQL.Add('Values(:CG, :ADI, :SOYADI, :MAIL, "1", "127.0.0.1", "ISYERI", :TELEFON, :FAX, "1", NOW()); ');

modul.Q_Customer.SQL.Add('INSERT INTO address (customer_id, firstname,lastname,company,VergiDaire, address_1, address_2, city, postcode, country_id, zone_id, VergiNo)');
modul.Q_Customer.SQL.Add('Values(LAST_INSERT_ID(), :ADI, :SOYADI, :FIRMA, :VD, :ADRES1, :ADRES2, :SEMT, :POSTAKOD, "215", :IL, :VN; ');

modul.Q_Customer.SQL.Add('UPDATE customer SET address_id = LAST_INSERT_ID() WHERE customer_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();');

modul.Q_Customer.ParamByName('CG').Value:=CG;
modul.Q_Customer.ParamByName('ADI').Value:=ADI;
modul.Q_Customer.ParamByName('SOYADI').Value:=SOYADI;
modul.Q_Customer.ParamByName('MAIL').Value:=MAIL;
modul.Q_Customer.ParamByName('TELEFON').Value:=TELEFON;
modul.Q_Customer.ParamByName('FAX').Value:=FAX;
modul.Q_Customer.ParamByName('FIRMA').Value:=UNVAN;
modul.Q_Customer.ParamByName('ADRES1').Value:=ADRES1;
modul.Q_Customer.ParamByName('ADRES2').Value:=ADRES2;
modul.Q_Customer.ParamByName('SEMT').Value:=SEMT;
modul.Q_Customer.ParamByName('POSTAKOD').Value:=POSTAKOD;
modul.Q_Customer.ParamByName('IL').Value:=IL;
modul.Q_Customer.ParamByName('VD').Value:=VergiD;
modul.Q_Customer.ParamByName('VN').Value:=VergiN;
modul.Q_Customer.ExecSQL;
```

Comment: In what way did it not work?  Did you get an error?

Comment: The line `'UPDATE customer SET address_id = LAST_INSERT_ID() WHERE customer_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();'` doesn't look right.

Comment: **Error :** 
SQL Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO address (customer_id, firstname,lastname,company,VergiDair' at line 1.

Comment: What is `modul.Q_Customer`?  And is there any reason why you can't call `modul.Q_Customer.ExecSQL` after each command?

Answer (score 0):

I think your line

```
modul.Q_Customer.SQL.Add('Values(LAST_INSERT_ID(), :ADI, :SOYADI, :FIRMA, :VD, :ADRES1, :ADRES2, :SEMT, :POSTAKOD, "215", :IL, :VN; ');
```

is missing a closing bracket after

```
VN;
```

Btw, it's always best to try and identify problems like this using a tool lkie MySQl Workbench.

Answer (score 0):

if you use ZEOS component, you can do it by :

```
function DoMySQLScript(Script: string; Args: array of const;
  Delimiter: string): boolean;
var ZSqlProcessor: TZSQLProcessor;
begin
  Result := False;
  Script := FormatQuery(Script, Args); // Format the Script with Args
  ZSqlProcessor:= TZSQLProcessor.Create(nil);
  try
      ZSqlProcessor.Delimiter := Delimiter;
      ZSqlProcessor.Script.Text := Script;
      ZSqlProcessor.Connection:= MyConnection; // the connection to you DB
      try
         ZSqlProcessor.Execute;
         Result := True;
      except
        Result := False;
      end;
  finally
    ZSqlProcessor.free;
  end;
end;
```

and

in you procedure you can do that :

```
begin
    S:= 'INSERT INTO customer (customer_group_id,firstname, lastname, email, approved, ip, model, telephone, fax, status, date_added)'
    'Values(%s, %s, %s, %s, "1", "127.0.0.1", "ISYERI", %s, %s, "1", NOW());'
    +' INSERT INTO address (customer_id, firstname,lastname,company,VergiDaire, address_1, address_2, city, postcode, country_id, zone_id, 
    +' VergiNo) Values(LAST_INSERT_ID(), %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, "215", %s, %s;'
    +'UPDATE customer SET address_id = LAST_INSERT_ID() WHERE customer_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();

    DoMySQLScript(S, [CG,ADI,SOYADI,MAIL,TELEFON,FAX,UNVAN,ADRES1,ADRES2,SEMT,POSTAKOD,IL,VergiD,VergiN], ';');
end;
```

NB: you can find ZSqlProcessor in ZSqlProcessor.pas

Comment: I think you should use a transaction. Since you have many parameters I suggest you wrap everything in one stored procedure.